# BQ25171 li ion charger chip

Tags: batteries, charger

if I want to use this chip to charge 2 li-ion cells in series, do I need 12 V as input voltage?
My idea was to use a micro USB port as voltage input (5 V), so if that is true I need step up the voltage from 5 V to 12 V?

Comment: Well if you're charging them to 4.2V you clearly need at least 8.4V. As that's > 5V yes you would need to step 5V up.

Comment: you also need to balance series charging for better lifespan with 10% bypass power

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a linear charger the input voltage should be higher than output voltage. By how much is shown by this graph in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/bq25171-q1).

[image: BQ25171 dropout voltage graph]

So yes, you'll have to step up 5V, possibly to 9V at least. There would be greater power wastage if you step up to 12V.

Also as Tony mentioned in the comments, it'll be critical to have a Battery Management System (BMS) that can prevent out of range parameters (V, I and T) as well as balance the two cells.